# Are abstract base classes redundant since Protocol classes were introduced?

Tags: python, duck-typing

I'm learning how to use Protocol classes that have been introduced in Python 3.8 ([PEP 544](https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/)).

So `typing.Protocol` classes are subclasses from `ABCMeta` and they are treated just like abstract classes are with the added benefit of allowing to use structural subtyping. I was trying to think of what I would use abstract base classes now and I'm drawing a blank.

What are the downsides of Protocol classes compared to ABCs (if any)? Maybe they come with a performance hit? Are there any specific cases where an ABC is still the best choice?

Comment: well, for starters, Protocols aren't enforced at runtime like `abc` classes are

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga, could you explain what you mean by `abc` getting enforced at runtime? And how that compares to Protocols? Because as far as I'm concerned, if I have a Protocol with an `abstractmethod` and I have a subclass that explicitly inherits from protocol, then it would be similarly enforced at the runtime, would it not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I prefer `ABC`s beacuse they're explicit. With a `Protocol` someone reading the code may not know your class is intended to implement an interface in another module or deep in a dependency. Similarly, you can accidentally conform to a `Protocol`'s signature, without conforming to its contract. For example, if a function accepts a

```
class Image(Protocol):
    def draw() -> None:
        ...
```

it's obviously not going to make sense with a

```
class Cowboy:
    def draw() -> None:
         ...
```

but the type checker would happily accept it.

Comment: Neat example! :)

Comment: @BrianO thanks, but not actually mine. I can't remember where I saw it

Comment: You still can be explicit and inherit from the Image. This is called explicit declaration https://peps.python.org/pep-0544/#explicitly-declaring-implementation

Comment: @zhukovgreen you have a good point, and this could address my first point to some degree. The problem remains wrt accidentally inheriting from protocols

Comment: Regarding your second point. Maybe the only disadvantage of using Protocol vs ABC, is that the check, in the case of Protocol, is happening not at runtime, but during the static type checking. So if you, because of any reason, missed the mypy error, then you can deploy and run your app and it will fail later than in the case of ABC. Personally, I don't see this as a big disadvantage especially in case when you have mypy as your linter

Comment: @zhukovgreen I don't follow. For the second point, there would be no mypy error with a `Protocol` - that's the problem

Comment: Mypy will raise an error at the place where you're instantiating the class, which implements the protocol, but does not contain all its methods. See mypy protocols documentation [1] at the third code snippet and text right above it 


[1] https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protocols.html#defining-subprotocols-and-subclassing-protocols

Comment: @zhukovgreen I think you've misunderstood. `Cowboy` _does_ implement all the methods of `Image`. There will be no mypy error

Comment: looking at the snippet you posted, I see what the confusion is. I'm talking about the problem that a `Protocol` is OK with structural subtypes (by definition), _in addition_ to concrete subtypes. The problem is that `Cowboy` will be a structural subtype of `Image` whether you want it to be or not. The fact that you _can_ explicitly inherit from a `Protocol` doesn't solve the problem of what happens when you don't

Comment: Agree, but the example with Cowboy is technically possible, but realistically - not. Because it is not just some coincidence of having the same interface, but you need to multiply it by the probability that you will put this Cowboy into some image_processor(image: Image). So this is really not probable